Orphan pages amp version
I am performing a redirection of my normal version php pages to amp version when accessed by mobile devices, now the problem is that when performing an analysis with the SEO tool ahrefs it shows me that these amp pages are orphans, taking into account that only These pages are accessed through redirection, how can I resolve this?
It occurs to me to remove the amp versions of the sitemap, however I don't know if it is the best way to solve this problem since this page is still required to be indexed
